# Unable to convert this Swift 2 code to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

This particular line is failing after I migrated from Swift 2 to Swift 3:

```
let brightness = ((((components?[0])! * 299.0) as CGFloat) + (((components?[1])! * 587.0) as CGFloat) + (((components?[2])! * 114.0)) as CGFloat) / (1000.0 as CGFloat)
```

Looking for help to convert this to Swift 3. I tried using this converter, but it's not getting it right: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

This is my original code:

```
extension UIColor {
    func isLight() -> Bool {
        let components = self.cgColor.components
        let brightness = ((((components?[0])! * 299.0) as CGFloat) + (((components?[1])! * 587.0) as CGFloat) + (((components?[2])! * 114.0)) as CGFloat) / (1000.0 as CGFloat)
        if brightness < 0.5 {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error/warning thrown?

Comment: Since you didn't include code for it, I defined `components`. And yes, like @rmaddy said, once I removed all the optional and forced-unwrapping, no build errors. So basically, my question is the same as Larme - what's the *exact* issue?

Comment: @dfd sorry forgot to include the whole code earlier. I just pasted my whole code which shows components.

Comment: First, since I didn't down-vote the question, I can't remove anything like that. Second, without trying your definition of `components` it looks okay to me syntactically. If that's the issue then maybe try rewriting that line of code from scratch? But if syntax isn't the issue, what do you mean by *"not getting it right"*?

Comment: @dfd to clarify, I edited my question with the whole code I am trying to convert. The converter just fails to convert, the output is gibberish.

Comment: It's not "the converter's" job to rewrite your code for you. It's not our job either. It's _your_ job. If you have a _question_, ask it.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by "gibberish" :-) but this does sound like a case where the converter just gets lost. Maybe this entire section should be coded manually? Assuming you know what the code should be doing of course. Sometimes manually dealing with syntax errors is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line should have failed under any version of Swift for being so unwieldily.

First off, safely unwrap the optional. And only use one cast at the end.

```
func isLight() -> Bool {
    if let components = self.cgColor.components {
        let brightness = CGFloat((components[0] * 299 + components[1] * 587 + components[2] * 114) / 1000)

        return brightness > 0.5
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This code assume the color is in the RGB colorspace. This code will fail otherwise (just like the original code would have failed).

Here's a safer implementation that handles both RGB and grayscale colors:

```
func isLight() -> Bool {
    var brightness: CGFloat = 0
    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var b: CGFloat = 0

    if self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: nil) {
        brightness = (r * 299 + g * 587 + b * 114) / 1000
    } else {
        var w: CGFloat = 0
        if self.getWhite(&w, alpha: nil) {
            brightness = w
        }
    }

    return brightness > 0.5
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I updated my question with the whole code, which shows what components is. Sorry, I had forgotten to include it earlier!

Comment: I updated the answer to better match your updated question.

Comment: @Prabhu Check my latest update. I fixed a critical mistake just after you accepted the answer.